# "Her computer is crashed." or " Her computer crashed

Tags: linking-verbs

The following are examples on "Problems at home and work" from English Vocabulary in use book.

> - The washing machine **is broken**.
> - Her computer **crashed**.

Both broken and crashed are adjectives. so when and why do we used adjective with linking verb (is)? and when don't we?

Can we say:

> - The washing machine **broke**.
> - Her computer **is crashed**.

Comment: *Crashed* in "Her computer crashed" is not an adjective.  It's just the past tense of the verb *to crash*.

Comment: It would be either, "Her computer crashed." Or, "Her computer **has** crashed."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that there's a general rule for this. You just have to learn the meaning and use of each word.

"The washing machine broke" and "the washing machine is broken" are both commonly used. Note the meaning is not quite the same. "Is broken" refers to the current state. "Broke" is a verb saying what happened. If I say, "My washing machine broke last January", that is not at all the same as "My washing machine is broken." It might well have been repaired sometime between last January and today.

People rarely if ever say "her computer is crashed". "Crashed" is an adjective, but it's rarely used. I think it's mostly used preceding a noun rather than as a predicative adjective. For example, "The crashed car was towed to the junk yard." Note "crashed" is also a verb, the past tense of "crash", as in, "Yesterday I crashed my car into a wall."

Comment: I wouldn't write *"Crashed" is an adjective* but rather *"Crashed" can be used as an adjective* and so on.

Comment: Technically, *crashed*, when used in this way, is a "participial adjective", I think, since it comes from the verb *to crash*, unlike a true adjective like *big*, which doesn't derive from a verb.

Answer (score 1):

Jay's answer is on-target, but to add to this:  We don't usually say "the computer is crashed" but we do say "the computer *has* crashed" to indicate a current condition.

> A: Hey could you print out my airline tickets?
>   B: I would, but my computer has crashed.

The difference between "crashed" and "broken" is most likely due to the fact that the expression "crash" (to refer to a computer malfunction) is relatively new and derives from slang (some discussion of this [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/etymology/comments/2ncyau/where_does_crash_as_applied_to_computers/)).  Newer words tend to conform more to idiomatic usage (what people say) and less to existing grammar rules.